# Probability with percent

Tags: probability, percentages

so my son has this question from school. I studied probability many many years ago and remember nothing at all about it(never used it afterwards).

I will be very thankful if someone can help me solve this question and also if someone can direct me to any place where I can learn these concepts again and test my learning...

Could someone solve and explain these questions please?

1. It is estimated that 30% of all adults in the US are obese and that 3% suffer from diabetes. If 2% of the population both is obese and diabetic, what percentage of the population has one disease only.
2. Welds of tubular joints can have two types of defects, , which we call A and B. Each weld produced has defect A with probability 0.064 and defect B with probability 0.043 and both defects with probability 0.025. Find the proportion of welds that has (a) Both defect A and B (b) Neither defect.

Any site which explains these concepts will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Recall that the probability that at least one of $A$ or $B$ (*possibly both*) is $\Pr(A\cup B)$ and that this can be expanded via inclusion-exclusion as $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$.

Comment: Now... frustratingly, the phrase "*Either...or*" is unfortunately ambiguous.  Some authors intend "*either...or*" to refer to the exclusive or, where "*either A or B*" refers to exactly one of $A$ or $B$ as having occurred but not both.  Other authors intend "*either...or*" to refer to the inclusive or, where "*either A or B*" to refer to at least one of $A$ or $B$ as having occurred including the possibility of both as having occurred.  You should check how your teacher and/or book intend this phrase to be used.  For exclusive or, note instead $\Pr(A\triangle B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-2\Pr(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's focus on your first exercise and take a look at the following diagram

[image]

Can you get the % of people suffering either of obesity or from diabetes?